# Under what conditions does RavenDB store variables of an instance of a class?

Tags: c#, ravendb

I read [on this tutorial](http://www.codemag.com/article/1203041) that RavenDB can be used to store instances of a class (such as the `Menu` object they use). I tried reproducing their example, but used a more minimal example, in C#:

```
using Raven.Client.Document;
using Raven.Client;

namespace Project3
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            IDocumentStore docStore = new DocumentStore()
            {
                Url = "http://localhost:8080",
                DefaultDatabase = "Northwind"
            };
            docStore.Initialize();
            var session = docStore.OpenSession();
            StringHolder strHolder = new StringHolder();
            session.Store(strHolder);
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    class StringHolder
    {
        string name = "kj";
    }
}
```

However, when I run this and check the database, this is what I see logged:

[image]

So the `StringHolder` parameter `name` isn't being stored. Why does this occur, when in the tutorial the analogous process with `Menu` and `Allergenics` causes the class variables to be stored in the resulting document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `name` of class `StringHolder` is private, so it does not get serialized. Only public properties are saved to the database.